# Porque al clickear en un boton me manda el contenido de un php

Tags: php, javascript, html, webservice

Hola estoy desarrollando un sistema de encuestas, pero cuando doy el boton guardar me retorna lo que tengo en mi paguina en "php" y no al listado de encuesta,

este es mi boton:

```
<input type="button" id="ok_nombre_encuesta" class="btn btn-primary ok_nombre" value="OK" />
```

que realiza esta accion

```
<form action="../../controller/Marketing/InsertarEncuesta.php" method="post">
```

y al darle click al boton me manda todo el php, que es este

```
    <?php
include '../../Model/db_config6.php';
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
$id_userSession =  $_SESSION["iduser"];

var_dump($_REQUEST); 


    try{
        $ch = curl_init();

        $abierta = array(); 
        for ($i=0; $i < count($_REQUEST['abierta_des']) ; $i++) { 
            $abierta[] = json_encode("{
                'question_dashboard' => '{$_REQUEST['abierta_des'][$i]}',
                'orderquestion_dashboard' => ($i + 1),
                'availabilityquestion_dashboard' => 1,
                'valuequestion_dashboard' => 2,
                'FKidquestiontype_dashboard' => 1
            }"); 
        }

        $ab = implode(',', $abierta); 
        $data = json_encode([
            "namesurvey_dashboard" => $_REQUEST['descripcion_a'],
            "versionsurvey_dashboard" => 1,
            "availablitysurvey_dashboard" => 1,
            "urlsurvey_dashboard" => null,
            "FKiduser_dashboard" => $id_userSession,
            "dataSurvey" => [$ab]
        ]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"Mi direccion webservice");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $server_output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
        curl_close ($ch);
        echo json_encode($server_output);  
    }
    catch(PDOException $error) {  
        $message = $error->getMessage();  
    }
```

y solo quiero que me retorne al listado de encuestas, todo esta hecho en javascript, así que no se que podría estar pasando realmente

Comment: tal vez te falte habilitar el soporte php para el servidor, que servidor es? ( apache, nginx, etc...)

Comment: Utilizo MAMP entonces utlilizo Apache

Comment: fijate en el panel de config del MAMP si PHP está habilitado y configurado

Comment: Si esta habilitado y configurado